# Why is zsh listening on port 22?

Tags: zsh, sshd, socket

I'm SSH'ed into a virtual machine and looking at `/proc/<pid>/net/tcp` for my zsh shell.  I see this line

```
sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
 ...
 3: 00000000:0016 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 19127 1 0000000000000000 100 0 0 10 0
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding what this is saying, zsh is listening on port 22.  I know that the zsh process is a descendant of the process running sshd but wouldn't sshd have closed the listening socket after forking?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Why is zsh listening on port 22?

It is not. Instead you are interpreting the shown information wrongly:
`/proc/pid/net/` shows network information about the full namespace the process is in, i.e. not only connections held open by the specific process. You might want to use `lsof -n -p pid` instead.

Comment: Or just use `netstat` and/or `ss` with the `-p` option (which shows for your process the pid of a listening socket or if you are root for all)

Comment: To-do: Learn about namespaces.  Thanks!

Comment: @DanielWalker Note that this doesn't have much to do with network namespaces. On a system without network namespaces, `/proc/pid/net` simply shows the whole system.